# Simple Meteor app wont work

Tags: javascript, meteor

I now started learning meteor running into this issue.

Edit: Issue is the file wont load on my windows system, in firefox or chrome browser at port 3000 (i even tried IE)

no data is displayed

Html:

```
<head>
    <title>People List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>People List </h1>
    {{> staff}}
</body>

<template name="staff">
    <p>{{ people.length }} Members</p>
    <ul>
        {{#each people}}
            {{> person}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="person">
    <li>
        <h2> {{ fullName }} </h2>
        <p>
            {{#if executive}}
                <strong> {{job}} </strong>
            {{else}}
                {{job}}
            {{/if}}
        </p>
    </li>
</template>
```

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {        
    Template.staff.people = [
        { fullName: "Daniel Prince", job: "CEO" },
        { fullName: "Jane Smith", job: "CTO" },
        { fullName: "Sophie Turner", job: "Developer" },
        { fullName: "Jack Lewis", job: "Designer" }
    ];

    Template.person.executive = function (){
        return !!this.job.match(/^C.*O$/);
    };
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This doesn’t answer it but instead of `!!this.job.match(/^C.*O$/)` why not use `(/^C.*O$/).test(this.job)`? That’s what `test` ist for.

Comment: What do you see on the command line when you run meteor? Something like Starting Proxy... ... App running at: http://localhost:3000/?

Comment: Check the browser debug console to see if there are js errors being reported by the browser.

Comment: The server runs properly but the data does not show in my browser at specified port :3000 nothing is being displayed only when I run it in  nitrous.io it works, I'm guessing my OS is the problem? (windows 8.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put your code into [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com) and it seems to be working perfectly there.   The link to the code is: http://meteorpad.com/pad/8Jie3NhFw3acCiQj4/SO%20Question

Without seeing the errors on the console and browser console, it will be hard to point you further.

The only change I might suggest would be to use the "helpers" method on the templates to setup your .people and .executive template helpers. (It seems like it's a more common way of doing it:

```
Template.staff.helpers({
  people : [
    { fullName: "Daniel Prince", job: "CEO"},
    { fullName: "Jane Smith", job: "CTO"},
    { fullName: "Sophie Turner", job: "Developer"},
    { fullName: "Jack Lewis", job: "Designer"}
  ]
});

Template.person.helpers({
    executive : function (){
        return !!this.job.match(/^C.*O$/);
    }
});
```

I wouldn't worry about the .helpers too much since it seemed to work correctly either way.